# How do I add arrays to an Arraylist of Arrays (Arraylist<Integer[]>)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to save the steps pf my player-character in a Sokoban-game.
So at first i want to fill an Array of int x and y, called "pos" with the actual position of the character.
And than i want to add this array to an ArrayList of Arrays, called "moves".

Array for one player-position:

```
int[] pos = new int [2];
```

ArrayList for all steps, the player made in the level:

```
Arraylist<Integer[]> moves = new ArrayList<>();
```

"int[]" makes an error, if placed inside the pointy brackets at the ArrayList.

How do i add the Array pos to the ArrayList moves?

Comment: Please share the exact text of the error and the code that causes it

Comment: Change `pos` to an `Integer[]`?

Comment: `int[]` != `Integer[]`. Why you declare one and use other?

Comment: `List<Integer[]> moves = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();` works for me

Comment: theese two lines are all, i have for my step-recorder, now. i cannot use    `Arraylist<int[]> moves = new ArrayList<>();`  , because "int" appears red underscored.

Comment: @Drachenbauer how are you compiling your java code? `ArrayList<int[]> moves = new ArrayList<>();` is valid java code

Comment: should i change the top one to `Integer[] pos = new Integer [2];` and how does the right call-line to add the Array to the ArrayList look?

Comment: oh now it is not more red undrescored, i dont know, why it was before...

Comment: and i still need the right way to fill the ArrayList.

Comment: Now i use this to fill my ArrayList: `public void savePos()
 {
  pos[0] = x;
  pos[1] = y;
  moves.add(pos);
 }` but it adds not only the new vaules, it turns all existing elements of the ArrayList to the actual vaules, too... what must i change here

Answer (score 2):

This works completely fine with **int[]**. However **int[] != Integer[]**, Use same in both places.

```
int[] pos = new int[2];
ArrayList<int[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
pos[0] = 1;
pos[1] = 2;
arrayList.add(pos);
System.out.println(arrayList.get(0)[0]+ " "+ arrayList.get(0)[1]);
```

Comment: i use this: `public void savePos()
 {
  pos[0] = x;
  pos[1] = y;
  moves.add(pos);
 }`  It´s very similar to yours. The Array and the ArrayList are class-variables. Every game-move, x or y changes. But it doesn´t only add the new vaules to the end of the ArrayList, it also replaces all existing list-elements with the new x and y vaules. Does the ArrayList hold instancas of the Array, wich change their vaules, if the vaules in the original array change? if yes, how do i add the vaules of each game-move as a new Array, that does not more interact with the original Array "pos"?

Comment: Now i use this: `public void savePos()
 {
  moves.add(new int[] {x, y});
 }`  and use the Array pos only in the method for the actual undo move-function and not more to save the positions.

Comment: ArrayList `moves` stores just the reference of the `int[] pos`  as a list element, not the whole array. Since you had the same array `pos`, updating values of this on each move and adding it to the list, it will store a new element indeed i.e. same reference of pos, hence you will get only the latest value.
The correct way will be to initialize a new array pos for every move, like you've done already

Answer (score 1):

`int` and `Integer` are two different things (I struggled with this as well when I first learned Java a long time ago.

`int` is a so-called *primitive datatype*, which means it is not an object. `Integer` is a *wrapper class*, basically a class whose only purpose is to contain an 
`int` so that it can be handled as an object. Since Java 5, there is "autoboxing", which means you can assign `int` values to `Integer` variables and vice versa, and the compiler will handle it silently. This tends to muddle the difference, but it still is there and important - such as in this case.

So if you want to store instances of `int[]` in an `ArrayList`, you need an `ArrayList<int[]>`, not an `ArrayList<Integer[]>`.

However, it is impossible to have an `ArrayList<int>` because `ArrayList` can only store Objects (the generic types exist only for the compiler), not primitives.

Oh yes, and to add an element to the list, use

```
Arraylist<int[]> moves = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(pos);
```

You could have found this in the [API doc for ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) - you should really learn to use the API doc, you will need it all the time to answer questions such as this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make class (for example Pos) and make x and y as attributes and make constructor. The you can make the type of arraylist  is Pos
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(new Pos(3,2));